# fgets printing two lines before input

Tags: c, fgets

So I am trying to write a program that will let me read a user input for data on an MP3 file using a doubly linked list data structure. I got most of the methods and functions to work, but when I am prompting the user to put in input it prints out two lines before the user can input for the first line. So for example

```
int main()
{
    int user_input = 0;

    while(!(user_input >= 4))
    {
            struct MP3_data_node* MP3_data;
            MP3_data = (struct MP3_data_node*)malloc(sizeof(struct MP3_data_node));

            printf("\nPlease select a number for one of the following instructions:\n");
            printf("0: add to list\n1: delete from list\n2: print the list from beginning to end\n3: print the list from end to beginning\n4: exit\n");

            scanf("%d", &user_input);

            if(user_input == 0)
            {
                    printf("Please provide the artist:");
                    fgets(MP3_data->artist,50,stdin);
                    printf("Please provide the album:");
                    fgets(MP3_data->artist,50,stdin);
                    printf("Please provide the song title:");
                    fgets(MP3_data->artist,50,stdin);
                    printf("Please provide the year the song was released: ");
                    scanf("%d", &MP3_data->yearReleased);
                    printf("Please provide the length of the song in seconds: ");
                    scanf("%d", &MP3_data->runTime);

                    addToList(MP3_data);
            }
...
```

So it prints out "Please provide the artist:Please provide the album:" and then let's me put the input in, so my question is how do I make it so that it prints:
Please provide the artist: (user input)
Please provide the album: (user input)
etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the right thing (`fgets`) int the first few prompts, then you switch to `scanf` which is the source of your problem. Use `fgets` (and `strtol`) instead of `scanf` and you will be fine. (And, the first `scanf` which causes the problem described in your question.)

The problem is that `scanf` *only* reads the digit part of whatever you enter. That means if you type <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, then the `scanf` reads the `1` and `2` but leaves the `Enter` in the input buffer for the next call to `fgets` or `scanf`. On the other hand, `fgets` reads everything you type including the `Enter`, avoiding this problem.